# Marbles Probability question using Bayes Rule

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Marbles Probability question using Bayes Rule
I have this question from my revision booklet that I cant understand.
A bag initially contained 4 white marbles and 9 black marbles. A marble was drawn and replaced by two marbles of the opposite color. Then another marble was drawn and also replaced by two marbles of the opposite color. A third marble was then drawn.

Find the probability that the first marble drawn was white if:

a) The second marble drawn was white

b) The third marble drawn was white

c) Both the second and third marbles drawn were white

My Attempt:

For a I used Bayes rule for a and computed the various probabilities and found out that a is 2/11. I'm not at all sure about b and c.

Comment: There are eight possibilities for the first three draws.  It might be worth starting by calculating the probabilities of each.

Comment: How are they 8?.  Isn't it 3! ways over the first 3 draws which is 6, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W_k$ be the event of drawing a white marble on the $k$-th draw, and $B_k$ the complementary event.

So your solution should look somewhat like:

(a) $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(W_1\mid W_2)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(W_1)~\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)}{\mathsf P(W_1)~\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)+\mathsf P(B_1)~\mathsf P(W_2\mid B_1)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\tfrac{4}{4+9}\tfrac{3}{3+11}}{\tfrac{4}{4+9}\tfrac{3}{3+11}+\tfrac{9}{4+9}\tfrac{6}{6+8}}&=\dfrac{4(4-1)}{4(4-1)+9(4+2)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{2}{11}&\checkmark\end{align}$$

The others use Bayes' Rule too.  Hint: tackle (c) first.

(b) $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(W_1\mid W_3)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(W_1,W_2,W_3)+\mathsf P(W_1,B_2,W_3)}{\mathsf P(W_1,W_2,W_3)+\mathsf P(W_1,B_2,W_3)+\mathsf P(B_1,W_2,W_3)+\mathsf P(B_1,B_2,W_3)}\\[2ex]&=\tfrac{\mathsf P(W_1)~\big(\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid W_1,W_2)+\mathsf P(B_2\mid W_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid W_1,B_2)\big)}{{\mathsf P(W_1)~\big(\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid W_1,W_2)} + {\mathsf P(B_2\mid W_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid W_1,B_2)\big)+\mathsf P(B_1)~\big(\mathsf P(W_2\mid B_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid B_1,W_2)+\mathsf P(B_2\mid B_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid B_1,B_2)\big)}}\end{align}$$

(c) $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(W_1\mid W_2,W_3)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(W_1)~\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid W_1,W_2)}{\mathsf P(W_1)~\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid W_1,W_2)+\mathsf P(B_1)~\mathsf P(W_2\mid B_1)~\mathsf P(W_3\mid B_1,W_2)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks Graham.  I used the same method to get 2/11 as you.  I understand C but am a bit confused how you derived/expanded Bayes rule in B.  Its not like something I have seen before.  Could you please clarify :)

Comment: It is just an application of Law of Total Probability, $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid C)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,C)}{\mathsf P(C)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,B,C)+\mathsf P(A,B^\complement,C)}{\mathsf P(C)}\\&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A)~\big(\mathsf P(B\mid A)~\mathsf P(C\mid A,B)+\mathsf P(B^\complement\mid A)~\mathsf P(C\mid A,B^\complement)\big)}{\mathsf P(C)}\end{align}$$And likewise to expand the denominator.

Comment: I understand.  And how would I read out $P(W_3| W_1,W_2)$.  The probability of 3rd being White given that the first and second are both white?

Comment: Yes.  Or. the probability of drawing white after you have removed two white balls and added four black balls.

Comment: Alright it makes sense, Ill give it a go.  Thanks again

Comment: Did you by chance have an answer that I could check with later?

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(W) = {4\over13}$ be the prob that the first draw is white

Then there will be 3 whites and 11 blacks

So if $P(WW)$ is the probability that both first and second draws are white , then $P(WW)= \frac 4{13}\times \frac 3{14}$

Similarly $P(B)=\frac 9{13}$ leaving 6 whites and 8 blacks

So $P(BW) = \frac{9}{13}\times \frac6{14}$

This is enough to get the answer for a)
$$P(W| WW\cup BW) =  \frac{P(WW)}{P(WW)+P(BW)} $$

for b) you will need more basic probabilities

e.g. $P(WWW) = \frac 4{13}\times \frac 3{14} \times \frac 2{15}$

$$P(W| WWW\cup WBW\cup BWW\cup BBW) \\=  \frac{P(WWW)+P(WBW)}{P(WWW)+P(WBW)+P(BWW)+P(BBW)} $$

Comment: Yes I already used that method and got an answer of 2/11,  Could you please get me started with b and c, I'm lost with those

Comment: @WW1 Nope. $(4\cdot 3)/(4\cdot 3+9\cdot 6)=(12)/(66)=2/11$

Comment: Sorry - my bad - it is 2/11

Comment: Thanks for Clarifying.  Still a bit confused how you go from $P(W| WWW\cup WBW\cup BWW\cup BBW) \\=  \frac{P(WWW)+P(WBW)}{P(WWW)+P(WBW)+P(BWW)+P(BBW)}$ to the second line.  Is that a version of Bayes rule and if so, which one?.

Comment: I'm using $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ - for b) the numerator is showing the probability that both the first and third draws are white - the denominator is the total probability that the third draw is white -  I get the answer 122/545